# Two application using the same Firebird Database

Tags: .net, firebird

In my company we are under strong software maintenance, we are rewriting some old applications. Now, for some reason that  is not relevant (partly because of that maintenance)  we need two different applications to use the same firebird database:

one will be writing, the other will be reading.

Both apps will be on the same machine(server) if that's relevant

Is it possible? I know it's a bad architecture, but we are changing it and for a little while I desperately need this functionality. Now I got this working, but there are some problems with writing to database ( duplicated records )

Update 1.

Thanks everyone for your answers.  Now after some tests I came to the conclusion, that is not the matter of two application at all. I got the writing app working all night (reading app turned off) and there are still some duplicated records:
[image: database_error]

Now, in the previous version of the program ( and previous version to the database), the problem didn't exist. I myself updated the database by adding index to the DateTime column:

`CREATE DESC INDEX IndexName ON TableName(DateTimeColumnName)`

I added a procedure that creates an index like that. Could it be the issue, that index causing these wrong entries? Or it doesn't have to tdo with anything and I have to look for a bug somewhere in the writing app?

Comment: You have two different connections. I do not see any problem for that.

Comment: Are you using Firebird Embedded or connecting through Firebird server? And if you are using Firebird Embedded, which OS and which Firebird version?

Comment: Also _"there are some problems with writing to database ( duplicated records )"_ sounds like a bug in your software or lack of proper constraints, which we can't possibly diagnose without more information. If you need help troubleshooting things, it might be better to post on firebird-support than here.

Comment: `I know it's a bad architecture` now, it is not. There might be some other details that make that architecture bad, but per se it is normal for several applications to work with the same data storage. For example Windows Management Instrumentation in SQL-like language. For another example - Windows Registry is a kind of database too (not relational one, but DB none the less), and many applications use those simultaneously, and that is ok, if programs and databases were designed for that.

Comment: I can only think of Interbase server where local protocol was mutually blocking and then two programs could interfere. But - with Interbase those programs (while being local) could be switched to TCP protocol, and in Yaffil/Firebird local protocol was reworked to be non-blocking. So, even for that much obsolete situation the "it's a bad architecture" claim is FAR too generic to be correct.

Comment: Thanks,I updated the post

Comment: Why do you consider those records duplicates? A timestamp as a key is - usually - a bad idea, and are you sure those are the exact same timestamps (Firebird timestamps have a resolution of 100 microseconds, not seconds as displayed here). This could be a matter of an imprecise timer causing a record to be added at say 11:19:46.0000 and one at 11:19:46.9999, or something else entirely. A non-unique index is only relevant for search and sorting, it is not a constraint. However, addressing that specific problem should be a separate question, or maybe even something for firebird-support.

Comment: @KarolŻurowski the marked records only have same value in the 3rd column, columns 1,2,6 are different, columns 4,5,7 are same through all the rows. So, I definitely see no duplicates there.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel am I wrong or in FB it is better to create ASCending index if the table is more often being added to (with ever-increasing values) than being read from?

Comment: @Arioch'The That is not relevant for this problem though.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your are using Firebird server (and not Firebird Embedded<sup>1</sup>), there is no problem to share a database with multiple applications. However, your database needs to be correctly designed, and your applications must correctly manage their transactions, etc.

Using a single database for multiple applications is not a bad architecture per se<sup>2</sup>, but you must consciously design your database and applications for that shared use.

Your remark that *"there are some problems with writing to database ( duplicated records )"*, sounds like either the design of the database (eg constraints), and/or the way your applications use the database (eg transaction isolation level, method of generating identifiers, etc) is deficient.

As an example, if your application generates identifiers using something like `select max(id) + 1 from sometable`, then that is definitely the wrong way (it is even wrong for single application access if that application can generate records concurrently). You should be using sequences (and preferably triggers) to generate ids.

---

1. If you are using Firebird Embedded, whether this works depends on the OS and Firebird version and configuration. Older Firebird Embedded versions on Windows require exclusive access to the database file.
2. As a counter-example, for micro-services, it is generally considered a bad architecture choice to share a single database with multiple services as that will reduce flexibility due to increased interdependence.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post. Yes, I am using Firebird Server